# Create filterable admin grid from external database table

Tags: magento2, collection, grid, uicomponent, filter

As the title says - I am trying to create an admin grid from an external database-table.

I was able to create one with an ui_component and some dirty tricks in my data provider - but the problem is, that I dont know how to get the values from the filter inputs.

Is there a best-practice on how to do this?

***edit:** see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally found my mistake(?!) - I can get the applied filters in my data-provider php file by using the `SessionManagerInterface`:

```
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;
class YourClassname extents AbstractDataProvider
{
  protected $session;
  
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        RequestInterface $request,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        Collection $collectionFactory,
        FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = [],
        Data $helper,
        SessionManagerInterface $session
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
        $this->collection = $collectionFactory->load();
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->prepareUpdateUrl();
        $this->session=$session;
    }
      public function getData()
    {

        $this->session->start();

        $filters=$this->request->getParam('filters');
        $servername = $this->helper->getConfig('configuration/database/host');
         $username = $this->helper->getConfig('configuration/database/username');
         $password = $this->helper->getConfig('configuration/database/password');
         $dbname = $this->helper->getConfig('configuration/database/name');
         $port = $this->helper->getConfig('configuration/database/port');
         $filters=$this->request->getParam('filters');

         
         try {
             $conn = new \PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;port=$port", $username, $password);
             $selection="SELECT * from table";
             foreach ($conn->query($selection) as $dbitem) {
          $item=
          [
           'id' => utf8_encode($dbitem['id']),
              'product_name' =>utf8_encode($dbitem['product_name'])
            ];
        array_push($items,$item);
        array_push($sessionitems,$item['id']);
         }

         $pagesize = intval($this->request->getParam('paging')['pageSize']);
         $pageCurrent = intval($this->request->getParam('paging')['current']);
         $pageoffset = ($pageCurrent - 1)*$pagesize;

         $collection=[
             'totalRecords' => count($items),
             'items' => array_slice($items,$pageoffset ,$pagesize),
         ];
          return $collection;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

And here is my layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">  
    <referenceBlock name="page.title">
        <action method="setPageTitle">
            <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">Import</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">    
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" template="Vendor_Module::yourphtmlfile.phtml"/>  <!-- change this part in your file -->
            <uiComponent name="importgrid"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

and the grid-file (listing):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">importgrid_data_source</item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <settings>
        <spinner>my_custom_columns</spinner>
        <deps>
            <dep>importgrid.importgrid_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>

    <dataSource name="importgrid_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\YourProvider</argument> <!-- change this to your provider -->
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">importgrid_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                  <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>                      
              </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">

            <action name="Export">
                <settings>
                    <url path="path-to-this-site"/>
                    <type>import</type>
                    <label translate="true">Import products</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
      </massaction>
        <filters name="listing_filters"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>

        <paging name="listing_paging"></paging>
    </listingToolbar>

    <columns name="my_custom_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">importgrid.importgrid.my_custom_columns.actions</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="controlVisibility" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="appendTo" xsi:type="string">importgrid.importgrid.listing_top.columns_controls</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">importgrid.importgrid.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>

        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>

                </item>

            </argument>
            <settings>
              <label translate="true">Selection</label>
            </settings>
        </selectionsColumn>

        <column name="id" sortOrder="1">
          <settings>
             <filter>text</filter>
             <dataType>text</dataType>
             <label translate="true">ID</label>
          </settings>
        </column>

        <column name="product_name" sortOrder="5">
          <settings>
             <filter>text</filter>
             <dataType>text</dataType>
             <label translate="true">Name</label>
          </settings>
        </column>

        <!-- add your additional colums here -->

    </columns>
</listing>
```

If anyone faces same problems, feel free to ask.

Comment: Hey Mario! I was wondering if you could share you di.xml where ever you declare the data provider, and the layout.xml for the listing.xml Thank you!

Comment: Sounds good. I don't think I phrased my question correctly. We are trying to accomplish this same task and wondering what your di, listing looks like to accomplish going the grid to an external DB. Thank you for the time.

Comment: I didnt declare the provider in the di.xml. 
But I can share the layout file and the listing file of course - see updated answer.

Comment: Awesome thank you. Another bother, did you do anything special in the Model/ResourceModel/Collection files? Normally they point to the Magento table but in this instance, they are pointing to the external table?

Comment: no, I just created the file:

`<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Foldername; \\ <- change it to your actual folder

use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection as DataCollection;

class Collection extends DataCollection
{

}
?>`

Btw. I added some more of my code to the data-provider in my answer, so you can see, how I get my connection and values from the db.

Comment: Thank you, sir! This is going to be super helpful!!

Comment: I struggle with this for about a week now - glad I did it before the weekend xD

Comment: last but not least - I got most parts done with looking at this question and answers:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209682/magento-2-ui-grid-non-db-dataprovider-and-pagination-issue

Comment: Hey Mario! I hope all is well! This has been super helpful. I am wondering if you came across an error for 

`PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Heartfelt\Platinum\Model\ResourceModel\Lookup\Collection::addOrder() in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-ui/DataProvider/AbstractDataProvider.php:208
Stack trace:`

Comment: I have 3 (mostly empty) functions in my data-provider.php:


`public function setLimit($offset, $size)
    {
    }

    public function addOrder($field, $direction)
    {
    }

    public function addFilter(\Magento\Framework\Api\Filter $filter)
    {
    }
`

Comment: Thanks Mario. Could more questions for you. 

What is the template used for in your layout xml?

Comment: ok, I think I have to explain, what the grid is made for in my case. In general, it imports products from the external database. 
The grid sends the selected entries to "itself" via the action-method. If nothing is sent, only the grid appears.

The template checks, if data was sent. If so, I send the entries (ids in my case) with ajax to a controller, that imports the given products. I did it that way, so I could send 1 entry at a time, and get no problems, when importing  >100 entries (server timeout etc.). 

So, in general, the template starts the import for the sent entries.

Comment: Awesome thanks. We finally got it, we had a bad naming convention in on of our files! I really appreciate all your help! You're a hero haha! Have a good one and stay safe!